# Android: How to use Image Button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash, imagebutton

I'm trying to use Image Button on my Android App, but every time I run it on my phone it crashes. This is the code i'm using. Can someone help me? I'd like to know where i'm screwing it. If i'm missing something from my code or something else. Any advise would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Added XML code

EDIT*: Added Logcat

**Code:**

```
ImageButton emergencia_nueve = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.telefono_nine);
        emergencia_nueve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String number="911";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(number));
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

**XML:**

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/telefono_nine"
        android:layout_width="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/alarmaizq"
        android:layout_below="@+id/alarmaizq"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/phone"
        android:onClick="telefono_nine"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/phone" />
```

Logcat:

```
04-28 08:44:24.199 1237-1237/? I/TrafficMonitor: gettimer:interval=2000
04-28 08:44:24.660 1237-1353/? E/libfingersense_wrapper: libfingersense.so was not loaded
04-28 08:44:24.768 1237-1353/? E/libfingersense_wrapper: libfingersense.so was not loaded
04-28 08:44:24.802 15853-15853/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
04-28 08:44:24.805 15853-15853/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
04-28 08:44:24.820 15853-15853/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: e.danma.drawer, PID: 15853
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                       at e.danma.drawer.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:107)
                                                       at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:154)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
                                                       at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:342)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5646)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22459)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
04-28 08:44:24.830 1237-1237/? I/SendBroadcastPermission: action:android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED, mPermissionType:0
04-28 08:44:24.832 1237-2988/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
04-28 08:44:24.838 1237-1250/? W/RMS.SmartShrinker: SmartShrinker is runing in pid =24275 reclaim mode = 4
04-28 08:44:24.839 1237-1250/? W/RMS.SmartShrinker: SmartShrinker is runing in pid =12011 reclaim mode = 4
04-28 08:44:24.839 1237-1250/? W/RMS.SmartShrinker: SmartShrinker is runing in pid =3851 reclaim mode = 4
04-28 08:44:24.839 1237-1250/? W/RMS.SmartShrinker: SmartShrinker is runing in pid =14034 reclaim mode = 4
04-28 08:44:24.840 15853-15853/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15853 SIG: 9
04-28 08:44:25.024 1237-9699/? I/SendBroadcastPermission: action:android.intent.action.SIG_STR, mPermissionType:0
04-28 08:44:25.024 1237-1237/? I/MQoS: onSignal: mSubId=0,currDataSubID=0
04-28 08:44:25.024 1237-1237/? I/MQoS: received cell-signal:5
04-28 08:44:25.026 407-418/? I/gralloc: alloc_device_free:586: Free handle(0x783f0a2a00)
04-28 08:44:25.026 407-418/? I/gralloc: alloc_device_free:586: Free handle(0x783f105100)
04-28 08:44:25.028 1237-20357/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
04-28 08:44:25.028 1237-20357/? I/MediaProcessHandler: processOp opType: 1, uid: 10179, pid: 15853
04-28 08:44:25.028 1237-20357/? W/MediaProcessHandler: remove target not exist, maybe the UI process: uid: 10179, pid: 15853
04-28 08:44:25.031 1547-1632/? I/HwMobileSignalController: subId:0 phoneType:1 networktype:3 targetClass:2 masterLevel:5 slaveLevel:-1
04-28 08:44:25.033 1237-1352/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'c92dc14 e.danma.drawer/e.danma.drawer.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-28 08:44:25.033 1237-1352/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'c92dc14 e.danma.drawer/e.danma.drawer.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-28 08:44:25.085 1237-1367/? E/WifiConfigManager: updateConfiguration freq=2437 BSSID=58:23:8c:6a:96:5a RSSI=-45 "HOME-965A"WPA_PSK
04-28 08:44:25.090 1237-4023/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'c92dc14 e.danma.drawer/e.danma.drawer.MainActivity (server)'
04-28 08:44:25.106 407-407/? I/gralloc: alloc_device_free:586: Free handle(0x783f0a2000)
04-28 08:44:25.129 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher onStart()
04-28 08:44:25.129 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher  Launcher.onStart() cost 0 ms
04-28 08:44:25.129 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher onResume()
04-28 08:44:25.134 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher doResumeWork()
04-28 08:44:25.148 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher  onResume mIsToUninstallApp = false
04-28 08:44:25.148 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher  Launcher hot start cost 19 ms
04-28 08:44:25.159 2507-2752/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-28 08:44:25.159 2507-2644/? E/HwLauncher: SettingsEx , no such field.
04-28 08:44:25.162 2507-2644/? W/HwLauncher: Clock getDataFormat the getSystemString failed.
04-28 08:44:25.171 407-1449/? I/gralloc: alloc_device_alloc:564: Alloc handle(0x783f0a2f00): interfmt=200000001, stride=1088, size=8486912, usage=0xb00
04-28 08:44:25.178 407-1449/? I/gralloc: alloc_device_alloc:564: Alloc handle(0x783f037e00): interfmt=200000001, stride=1088, size=8486912, usage=0xb00
04-28 08:44:25.181 1547-1547/? I/PhoneStatusBarPolicy: updateBluetooth:::setBluetoothBatteryEnable false.
04-28 08:44:25.181 1547-1547/? I/PhoneStatusBarPolicy: updateBluetooth::bluetoothEnabled:false, bluetoothConnected=false, bluetoothTransfering=false
04-28 08:44:25.184 407-1449/? I/gralloc: alloc_device_alloc:564: Alloc handle(0x783f037200): interfmt=200000001, stride=1088, size=8486912, usage=0xb00
04-28 08:44:25.190 2507-2752/? E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 1
04-28 08:44:25.199 2507-2752/? E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 34359738371
04-28 08:44:25.201 2507-2752/? E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 68719476744
04-28 08:44:25.203 2507-2752/? E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 68719476736
04-28 08:44:25.230 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher.Utilities  unread scaledHeight = 54;sBigIconSize = 172
04-28 08:44:25.269 1237-1353/? E/libfingersense_wrapper: libfingersense.so was not loaded
04-28 08:44:25.282 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: FPSMonitor  [Launcher , dispatchTouchEvent begin, false, true] down event  x = 355 y = 661
04-28 08:44:25.282 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher workspaceTranslationX = 0.0
04-28 08:44:25.283 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: FPSMonitor  [PagedView , onIntercept] down event  x = 355 y = 661
04-28 08:44:25.284 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: FPSMonitor  [Launcher , dispatchTouchEvent end, false, true] down event  x = 355 y = 661
04-28 08:44:25.327 1237-1353/? E/libfingersense_wrapper: libfingersense.so was not loaded
04-28 08:44:25.328 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: FPSMonitor  [Launcher , dispatchTouchEvent begin, false, true] up event  x = 355 y = 661
04-28 08:44:25.329 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: FPSMonitor  [PagedView , onIntercept] up event  x = 355 y = 661
04-28 08:44:25.329 2507-2507/? I/HwLauncher: FPSMonitor  [Launcher , dispatchTouchEvent end, false, true] up event  x = 355 y = 661
04-28 08:44:25.699 2507-2752/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
04-28 08:44:25.699 2507-2752/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
04-28 08:44:26.201 1237-1237/? I/TrafficMonitor: update:rxPkts:0,txPkts:0,rxBytes:0,txBytes:0
04-28 08:44:26.201 1237-1237/? I/TrafficMonitor: start expired. level:-1
```

Comment: Please add the code where R.id.telefono_nine is defined in your layout XML file :)

Comment: XML code added!

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Please provide Stacktrace

Comment: Just added LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly inflate the XML where your image button is placed.
You can do it in your main Activity by just calling set content view to that xml.

`setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);`

Then do your rest code implementation.

Also do that in your `onCreate` of your activity.